# Wordpress user roles restrictions plug in

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Hi is there any plug in that admin can share  posts on each user? And only when a user log in on page can see their relative posts and updates of them?

Comment: Is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Advanced Access Manager` plugin and you can manage everything in your site with this plugin from the admin panel.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-access-manager/